# Parse (JS SDK) saving array of images as attribute of object

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, associations

What I want in the end:

I want to have a Product that has a few images (up to 10).

This is how I thought I would do this:

```js
// I have an "images" array of HTML5 File objects from an <input>

let parseImages = images.map( (image) => {
  return new Parse.File(image.name, image);
});


let product = new Product({
  name: name,
  price: price,
  description: description,
  images: parseImages
});

product.save()
  .then(
    (savedProduct) => {
      // I'm happy here with a saved Product that has an array of images
      // This did not happen
    },
    (error) => { 
      console.log('Error saving images: ', error.code, error.message) 
      // Sadly I didn't get here either
    }
  );
```

^ That did not work.

Then I tried this…

```js
let product = new Product({
  name: name,
  price: price,
  description: description
});

let parseImages = images.map( (image) => {
  return new Parse.File(image.name, image);
});

Parse.Object.saveAll(parseImages)
  .then(
    (savedImages) => {
      product.save()
        .then(
          (savedProduct) => {
            savedProduct.add('images', images);
            savedProduct.save()
              .then(
                (savedProductWithImages) => {
                  // still not getting here
                },
                (error) => {}
              );
          },
          (error) => { console.log('Error saving product: ', error.code, error.message) }
        );
    },
    (error) => { console.log('Error saving images: ', error.code, error.message) }
  );
```

That didn't work either.

Every time I don't even make it to the promise rejection. I get a…

```
Converting circular structure to JSON
```

error.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: i have the same issue that i wanted to post here. Neither i can upload many images assosiated to one "product". If someone could help. I will bump this!